# Let $F : C([0,1]) \longrightarrow C([0,1])$ be defined by $F(f)(x) = \sin(f(x))$ for $f \in C([0,1])$ and $x \in [0,1]$. Show that $F$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I think I have a proof for this statement, but it relies only weakly on the continuity of $f$, which may not even be necessary after all. Is this reasoning correct?

We need to show that given $\varepsilon > 0$, $\; \exists \delta > 0$ such that if $||f - f_0|| < \delta$, then $||\sin(f) - \sin(f_0)|| < \varepsilon$; that is, if $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x) - f_0(x)| < \delta$ then $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|\sin(f(x)) - \sin(f_0(x))| < \varepsilon$.

Fix $f_0 \in C([0,1])$ and let $f$ satisfy $\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x) - f_0(x)| < \delta$. Without loss of generality, suppose $f(x) < f_0(x)$ (if they are equal the statement is trivial, otherwise just reverse the roles). Then, by the Mean Value Theorem, there exists a $c$ with $f(x) < c < f_0(x)$ such that $|\sin(f(x)) - \sin(f_0(x))| \leq |\cos(c)| |f(x) - f_0(x)|$, which implies that $|\sin(f(x)) - \sin(f_0(x))| \leq |f(x) - f_0(x)| < \delta$. Since this is true for all $x$, the supremum can be passed into the inequality and we have the required statement.

To me it seems that the continuity only plays a role in ensuring the supremum is always well-defined, but by the definition of continuity I'm not so sure it even needs to always be well-defined, it just requires that the statement holds when it is. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous then $F$ may not be continuous. Take $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $f(x)=1$ on $(1/2,1]$ for instance.

Comment: @nayrb The function $F$ is or is not continuous, irrespectively of which $f$ one chooses. You probably meant that $F(f)$ could be not continuous when $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @Did Yes, of course. Good clarification.

Comment: @mayrb Ok, I see with that example that it is clearly necessary. But where does this enter in the proof? I mentioned in response to another answer that my only reasoning was ensuring the supremum was well-defined, but need that be the case for the definition of continuity? As long as we guarantee that *when* the sup is defined and less than delta, we still have the corresponding epsilon inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 1$\implies$2$\implies$3, where:

1. For every $(u,v)$, $|\sin u-\sin v|\leqslant|u-v|$
2. For every $x$ and every $(f,g)$, $|F(f)(x)-F(g)(x)|\leqslant|f(x)-g(x)|$
3. For every $(f,g)$, $\|F(f)-F(g)\|_\infty\leqslant\|f-g\|_\infty$

Comment: Thanks...I'm still stuck on where the continuity enters though. Where in this proof does it rely on the fact that f and g are continuous?

Comment: It does not. If $f_n\to f$ for the norm $\|\ \|_\infty$, whether $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous or not, then $F(f_n)\to F(f)$ for the norm $\|\ \|_\infty$. In other words, $F:(L^\infty([0,1]),\|\ \|_\infty)\to (L^\infty([0,1]),\|\ \|_\infty)$ is continuous, not only $F:(C([0,1]),\|\ \|_\infty)\to (C([0,1]),\|\ \|_\infty)$.

Comment: Great, thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. If we have any two functions $f$ and $g$ (not necessarily continuous) which are appropriately "uniformly close", then $\sin(f)$ and $\sin(g)$ are "uniformly close" as well. And you're correct about the role of continuity being that the supremum is well-defined.

Your proof seems correct to me (you should only be a little more careful on the beggining, maybe write something like: "Fix $f_0\in C([0,1])$. Let $\delta>0$, and let $f$ satisfy $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-f_0(x)|<\delta$. Let $x\in [0,1]$. Let's show that $|\sin(f(x))-\sin(f_0(x))|<\delta$. Without loss [...]")

About th supremum being well-defined, this is [Weierstrass extreme value/boundedness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)

Comment: Why must the supremum be well-defined? To me, the definition of continuity doesn't mean this is necessary, only that the epsilon-statement holds true *whenever* the delta statement holds true. If the supremum isn't well-defined, couldn't it just be ignored for that pair of f, g?